# How can I transfer Google contacts with photos to another account?

Tags: google-contacts

When I export my contacts from Google Contacts (contacts.google.com), none of my contact's photos are included.

Additionally, when I attempt to import a VCF file containing photos, the web interface doesn't import the contact's photos.

How can I transfer my contacts, with photos, to another Google account?

Answer (score 2):

One of the fastest methods I found was using the [Google Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.contacts&hl=en) app:

1. Make sure you have 2 Google accounts added to your phone.
2. Go to the source account and choose 'Select All' from the drop down on the right.
3. Then from the same drop down select 'Move to another account' and select your target account.

It might take some time. It would be nice if Google could provide some nice batch way of doing that from the web as you initially tried.

Note: this will MOVE (not copy) the contacts.

Comment: This requires a (android) phone. Also it seems it looses all the Google Contacts labels.

Answer (score 0):

Contacts exported or imported on an Android device will retain the photos.

**To export (on an Android device):**

1. Open the *Contacts* app
2. Open the *Three Line* menu
3. Tap *Settings*
4. Scroll down and select *Export*
5. Check the accounts contacts you wish to export
6. Tap *EXPORT TO .VCF FILE*

**To import (on an Android device):**

1. Open the *Contacts* app
2. Open the *Three Line* menu
3. Tap *Settings*
4. Scroll down and select *Import*
5. Tap ".vcf file"
6. Select the account to import the contacts to
7. Select the .vcf file

Comment: As this is Web Applications, we generally expect solutions to use a web interface. Not everyone has an Android phone.

Comment: Does this include photos as well?

Comment: Yes, this solution would also include photos.

Answer (score 0):

I made an export of Google contacts with .vcf, and imported into mailbox.org. 
The photos did migrate.

Steps:

1. Google Contacts web interface:
   https://contacts.google.com/u/0/#contacts
2. Select all contacts
3. Drop down menu for all selected contacts
4. Export
5. Export as vCard (for iOS Contacts)
6. Save the file: MyGoogleContactsExport.vcf
7. Mailbox.org Contacts interface
8. My address book \ Contacts \ Drop down menu
9. Import
10. Format: vCard
11. Upload: MyGoogleContactsExport.vcf
12. Click on Import

It only imports 2 or 3 e-mail addresses, that is a drawback of this solution.

For more e-mail addresses, try this solution with DAVx5 on an Android phone.
https://userforum-en.mailbox.org/topic/how-to-syc-contacts-calendar-with-davx5-mailbox-org-android

Comment: Could you please add step-by-step instructions as to how you did that?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old thread, but as it shows high in Google hits let me add my experience.
Having spent some hours on this and the alternative answers, here is what fully works:

- This DavX5 application mentioned above and its CardDav synchronization. Yes, it is finicky, but it still works as of 2022-10, see [here for technical details](https://www.davx5.com/tested-with/google), including:

  Before you can sign in with DAVx⁵, you have to prepare your Google account:
  Activate 2-step verification for your Google account.
  Then create an app password for DAVx⁵ and use it for setting up DAVx⁵...
  (Tip: to enable Google Authenticator as the second step, you have to agree to Google sending an SMS first, sigh.)
- Google mail and contact account migration, well hidden in: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1/#settings/accounts

  Import mail and contacts:
  Importing – It may take several hours (sometimes up to 2 days) before you start to see imported messages. You can leave this page and the import will continue...
  Import from another address

See also [a related thread here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114995/how-can-i-transfer-google-contacts-with-photos-to-another-account).

What semi-works:

- [Thunderbird](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/extensions/) and its CardDav address books.
  You can link Google, GMX etc. fine there, but moving records en masse is a hit-and-miss affair: sometimes the photos get deleted, the extra fields go missing or the whole process gets stuck